# Early 2008 Macbook Pro won't eject Windows 7 Professional disc when prompted

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, eject

Im using an Early 2008 Macbook Pro and I am having a problem completing my BootCamp installation due to the fact that when I am prompted to eject the windows disc, I have no clue how to. I've tried plenty times pressing the eject disc button but no luck, and I'm guessing it's because the laptop is trying to run as a Microsoft product and won't respond to the Macintosh buttons. Please help, I really want to install some other disc but they're only for Windows and I'm tired of dealing with Windows computers. Thank you for your time. : )

Comment: Is the windows disc the full version or an upgrade? If using an upgrade, you must first have a previous version of windows installed on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can force eject the disc by restating. When you hear the chime Press COMMAND-E or hold down the trackpad/mouse button.